# How to check if Apache has SNI installed on Debian 8

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, ssl

I'm running a Linux server with Debian 8 installed. It is currently using a LAMP stack. I am using virtualhosts to run several sites from a single domain address.

I am looking to install some SSL certificates onto the websites I am hosting, but I need to ensure that SNI is installed. I believe it may have been installed at an earlier date.

I am fairly new to sysadmin-esque work, so I'm not sure if this is a basic task. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Apache HTTPd wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI):

> How can you tell if your Apache build supports SNI? If you configure multiple name-based virtual hosts for an address where SSL is configured, and SNI isn't built into your Apache, then upon Apache startup a message like "You should not use name-based virtual hosts in conjunction with SSL!!" will occur in the error log. If SNI is built in, then the error log will show "[warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)".

So without knowing anything about your HTTPd, you can set up multiple name-based virtual hosts with SSL, and check the messages given during startup.

On Debian 8, if you’re using the packaged HTTPd ([`apache2`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apache2) and related packages), SNI is available by default.